# Unexpected reboots of a Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, reboot

I have a Ubuntu Linux machine acting as a bridge/firewall between the Internet and my home network. This host works 24x7 unattended. It just sends me a report every day. I've paid attention that in the last several months there were several unexpected reboots of the machine. There were no suspicious logins. I've also checked the `/var/log/syslog` but could not find anything related (by time) to the reboots.

How can I find the reason for the reboots?

Comment: Any power outages?

Comment: Nothing. It is connected to UPS and consumes 5 W only. Further, it does not start automatically when power restores. I tested it.